# In Python parse a generic JSON structure looking for specific values

Tags: python, json, string, parsing

I'm trying to parse a JSON structure and looking for specific values.

Here an example of a possibile data to parse:

```
{
    "objects": [
        {
            "from": 44,
            "my_ref": "http://192.168.10.1/index.php",
            "allow": "no",
            "to": 10
        },
        {
            "from": 20,
            "my_ref": "http://192.168.10.2/index.php",
            "allow": "mandatory",
            "to": 0
        }
    ],
    "comment": "My PHP",
    "identifiable_with_user": true,
    "key": 10,
    "link": [
        {
            "href": "http://192.168.10.1/index.php",
            "method": "GET",
            "rel": "self",
            "type": "website"
        },
        {
            "href": "http://192.168.10.5/identifiable.php",
            "method": "GET",
            "rel": "account_info"
        }
    ],
    "name": "Accounts",
    "read_only": true,
    "system": true,
    "system_key": 20,
    "tls_match_ref": "http://192.168.10.5/accounts.php"
}
```

I need to extract all the values identified by the key *ref (like my_ref, href, etc...) in a generic JSON structure.  I just need to extract the URL and then perform some actions:

```
for entities in JSON_structure 
    URL= "take the URL corresponding to the ref key"
    so something with the URL
```

I tried using .items() filtering "http://" string but didn't work

```
 URL = {k:v for (k,v) in element_detail.items() if "http://" in k or v}
```

Comment: why not look directly for keys with ref in it ?

Comment: also could you add a bit more code so that people could try to fix it

Comment: I just tried looking for the key but it crashes. In "element_detail" I have the JSON data (like example above)

for element_URL in element_detail["ref"]:
                print element_URL

Comment: Pleas let us know a bit more about the crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should parse the data then look for the keys with ref in it.

That does the trick :

```
import json

def parse(root):
  for k,v in root.items():
    if isinstance(v, list):
      for e in v:
        parse(e)
    else:
      if 'ref' in k:
        print(k + ':' + v)


json_data = '{\
  "objects": [\
    { "from": 44, "my_ref": "http://192.168.10.1/index.php", "allow": "no", "to": 10 },\
    { "from": 20, "my_ref": "http://192.168.10.2/index.php", "allow": "mandatory", "to": 0 }\
  ],\
  "comment": "My PHP",\
  "identifiable_with_user": true,\
  "key": 10,\
  "link": [\
    { "href": "http://192.168.10.1/index.php", "method": "GET", "rel": "self", "type": "website" },\
    { "href": "http://192.168.10.5/identifiable.php", "method": "GET", "rel": "account_info" }\
  ],\
  "name": "Accounts",\
  "read_only": true,\
  "system": true,\
  "system_key": 20,\
  "tls_match_ref": "http://192.168.10.5/accounts.php"\
}'

data = json.loads(json_data)
parse(data)
```

Output :

```
href:http://192.168.10.1/index.php
href:http://192.168.10.5/identifiable.php
my_ref:http://192.168.10.1/index.php
my_ref:http://192.168.10.2/index.php
tls_match_ref:http://192.168.10.5/accounts.php
```